# Move image like facebook chat

Tags: ios, objective-c, facebook, animation, core-animation

I want to make animation like `facebook chat`: chat heads. I created a icon. It worked fine and quite smooth. I created more icons. They worked, too. But **not consistent** like `facebook`.  Is there any idea or reference to implement the features move?

Like this video:
[Chat heads](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=Bm-tNnmFaUA)

Comment: what is  features move?

Comment: Try this sample from github..

https://github.com/Tech-Dev-Mobile/IOS-Message-Chat

Comment: @square: i mean chatheads. i edited

Comment: @SVM-RAJESH: i want to make animation, not send or receive message.

Answer (score 2):

Try this May be help full .. But It's have done for UIButton..

```
 UIButton *button = [UIButton buttonWithType:UIButtonTypeRoundedRect];
[button setTitle:@"Drag me!" forState:UIControlStateNormal];

// add drag listener
[button addTarget:self action:@selector(wasDragged:withEvent:)
 forControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchDragInside];

// center and size
button.frame = CGRectMake((self.view.bounds.size.width - 100)/2.0,
                          (self.view.bounds.size.height - 50)/2.0,
                          100, 50);

// add it, centered

[self.view addSubview:button];


- (void)wasDragged:(UIButton *)button withEvent:(UIEvent *)event
{
   // get the touch
UITouch *touch = [[event touchesForView:button] anyObject];

// get delta
CGPoint previousLocation = [touch previousLocationInView:button];
CGPoint location = [touch locationInView:button];
CGFloat delta_x = location.x - previousLocation.x;
CGFloat delta_y = location.y - previousLocation.y;

// move button
button.center = CGPointMake(button.center.x + delta_x,
                            button.center.y + delta_y);
 }
```

I got this from here ..for more info you can find here .. [Draggable UIButton makes in iPhone & iPad](http://www.jogendra.com/2013/07/draggable-buttons-makes-in-iphone-ipad.html)